# Hip popping on Ab Ripper X workout

Tags: stretching, hip

There are a few exercises in the [Ab Ripper X](http://www.freeworkoutguides.com/node/680) workout that cause a pop in my hip on each rep:

In & Out - on extending/straightening

Fifer Scissor - on switching legs

Are there stretches or proper forms to do to prevent this popping? It doesn't cause pain, but it is very uncomfortable and it distracts from the workout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it is something called ["snapping hip syndrome."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapping_hip_syndrome)  The wiki article doesn't provide any ground-breaking info, but it's a good overview of the condition.  If it starts causing you pain, see a doctor.  I get this with my left hip when I do side kicks.  I just learned to live with it.

Comment: This would happen to me when I did sit-ups, which I stopped doing some time back when I learned how NG they are... but now it happens when I do the dead bug, although only when I stretch out my *right* leg, not my left.